# How to convert a PNG to 1-bit BMP

Tags: image, imagemagick, png, bmp

So, I'm trying to understand how PNG to BMP conversion actually takes place.  I created the following 8x8 pixel PNG using a tool online:

[image]

I then performed a conversion using the ImageMagik tool in OSX terminal:

`$ convert -monochrome pic.png pic.bmp`

Afterwards, I did a hexdump of the image:

`$ hexdump -C pic.bmp
00000000  42 4d 4a 01 00 00 00 00  00 00 8a 00 00 00 7c 00  |BMJ...........|.|
00000010  00 00 08 00 00 00 08 00  00 00 01 00 18 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  00 00 c0 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ff 00 00 ff 00 00 ff 00  |................|
00000040  00 00 00 00 00 ff 42 47  52 73 8f c2 f5 28 51 b8  |......BGRs...(Q.|
00000050  1e 15 1e 85 eb 01 33 33  33 13 66 66 66 26 66 66  |......333.fff&ff|
00000060  66 06 99 99 99 09 3d 0a  d7 03 28 5c 8f 32 00 00  |f.....=...(\.2..|
00000070  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000080  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff  |................|
00000090  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |................|
*
00000130  ff ff 00 00 00 ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |................|
00000140  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff                    |..........|
0000014a`

So, obviously we have a BMP header from 0x00 - 0x8C.  Then we have FF for white pixels and 00 for black.  That all makes sense, but the structure of the output doesn't.  So far, it seems that there is a 3 to 1 ratio.  3 bytes per pixel.  I'm assuming this means black, white, no-color?

I need to fully understand why there are 3 bytes per pixel instead of 2.  Ideally, I would like a binary 1 or 0 for each pixel instead.  Is there a way to do this?  And if not, can someone please explain the layout of bytes?  Specifically: Why are the 3 00s at 0x132 - 0x134 and not the very beginning?

Thanks

Comment: probably a color bmp, which means 24bits-per-color (8bit red, 8bit green, 8bit blue). if you want a true B&W bitmap, you have to output the appropriate bmp header options to say it's B&W.

Comment: The BMP file format is well explained on its Wikipedia page. Why not start there? For one, it tells you what byte in that header indicates the bit depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which question this will answer, but from the [Usage docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#bmp)

> IM can not produce BMP's at depth levels other than 8.  However you can
>     use NetPBM image processing set to do the final conversion to other depth
>     levels (This needs at least a Q16 version of IM)...

So if we leverage NetPBM

```
$ convert pic.png -depth 1  ppm:- | hexdump
```

Which gives  (Note the values are 0 & 1, but you still have a RGB channels)

```
0000000 50 36 0a 38 20 38 0a 31 0a 00 00 00 01 01 01 01
0000010 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
*
00000c0 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01                     
00000c9
```

So a workaround my be as simple as

```
$ convert pic.png -depth 1  ppm:- | pnmdepth 1 | ppm2bmp > pic.bmp
```

Answer (score 5):

Imagemagick, in fact, does support 1-bit BMP, if using either BMP3 or BMP2 formats, but not BMP4 which is just BMP. So if you want 1-bit depth per channel, then do

Input:

[image]

```
convert image.png -depth 1 BMP3:result.bmp
```

[image]

If you want a 1-bit depth for the whole image (i.e. binary), then do

```
convert image.png -depth 1 -type bilevel BMP3:result2.bmp
```

[image]

Or

```
convert image.png -depth 1 -threshold 50% BMP3:result3.bmp
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora 27 that command is:

```
$ convert pic.png -depth 1  ppm:- | pnmdepth 1 | ppmtobmp > pic.bmp
```

You need:

```
$  dnf install netpbm-progs
```

Comment: Your answer is about Fedora. Author is on MacOSX. You should remove your response.